# Child and Parent Database - Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have developed two tables in Spring Boot, User and UserMeta. User is the parent and UserMeta is the child table. The foreign-key is user_id. I may be looking at it the wrong way, but I want to be able to first create an entity of User. Then, I want to create an entity of UserMeta. Simply UserMeta should contain additional data to User.

However, when first creating a User and then a UserMeta entity, I get e new User entity (ending up with two User entities and one UserMeta entity.)

The problem I think is that I create a UserMeta object with a User, since I want to have a relationship between User and UserMeta. But if I want to be able to first create a User and then a UserMeta, should I simply ignore a foreign-key? Or, does it exists another way of creating a UserMeta entity without creating a new User?

User

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
    //@OneToOne(optional=false)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private UserMeta userMeta;
    
    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }   
}
```

UserMeta

```
public class UserMeta {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_meta_sequence", sequenceName = "user_meta_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_meta_sequence")
    private Long userMeta_Id;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "user_Id",
            referencedColumnName="userId"
            )
    private User user;

    public UserMeta(String lastName, int age, User user){
        this.lastname = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

UserService

```java
public interface UserService {
    User saveUser(User user);
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        super();
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

@Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

UserController

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    private UserService userService; 
    
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }
@PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.saveUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

UserMetaRepository

```
public interface UserMetaRepository extends CrudRepository<UserMeta, Long> {
}
```

UserMetaService

```
public interface UserMetaService {
    UserMeta saveUserMeta(UserMeta userMeta); 
}
```

UserMetaServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserMetaServiceImpl implements UserMetaService{
    
    private UserMetaRepository userMetaRepo; 
    
    public UserMetaServiceImpl(UserMetaRepository userMetaRepo) {
        super(); 
        this.userMetaRepo = userMetaRepo; 
    }

    @Override
    public UserMeta saveUserMeta(UserMeta userMeta) {
        return this.userMetaRepo.save(userMeta); 
    }

}
```

UserMetaController

```
@RestController
public class UserMetaController {

    public UserMetaService userMetaService; 

    public UserMetaController(UserMetaService service) {
        super();
        this.userMetaService = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("/userMeta")
    public ResponseEntity<UserMeta> saveUserMeta(@RequestBody UserMeta userMeta) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserMeta>(this.userMetaService.saveUserMeta(userMeta), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you're creating the `User` and `UserMeta` objects, and saving them? I suspect that will shed more light on what's going on.

Comment: it is common problem that users do not use the entities returned from their save calls. Spring 'save' will take your entity instance and decide to call either JPA's merge OR JPAs persist on the entity instance. They have very different mechanics; if persist is used, the entity passed in will be the same as the entity save returns, and have its sequence assigned when the transaction is flushed. If merge is used, it creates and passes back an entirely different instance; only the one passed back will have identity set. You must use the one passed back that has identity set in your object graph.

Comment: @Chris very interesting, I didn't know this and it feels like I got a lot to read about know. But, imagine that I have a web-app. Firstly, a user creates an account via as the Aser table above. Secondly, the user add information as in UserMeta table. Am I thinking about this the right way or should the new user directly create a UserTable entity (some null values), evoking a new User entity?

Comment: @kaan very simple, I'm just using PostMan sending JSON-objects. Firstly, I send a user object with provided key-value pairs. Then, I'm sending the following object to UserMeta: {
    "lastName":"foo",
    "age":1,
    "user":{
        "username":"foo", 
        "password":"bar", 
        "email":"foo-bar"
        }
}

Comment: @Chris , I wish to avoid creating a new entity with every field from the beginning. As in this example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_advanced_mappings.htm#. Is there a way around this or should I simply create a UserMeta entity with null values?

Comment: To be helpful, we would need to see the code you've written that creates objects, calls `.save()`, etc - whatever code you've written that _uses_ `User` and `UserMeta`. As Chris elaborated on, it's really common that the _usage_ is the source of your problem (also, your code for `User` and `UserMeta` looks fine).

Comment: @kaan I have updated the question with all my classes now.  I'm thinking about if I have misunderstood something fundamental here. I must be able to create a parent entity before a child entity, right? Or, is the proper way to create a parent entity through the child and eventually fill the child entity with nans?

Comment: @Chris I have updated my question and now display all the classes

Comment: In your JSON, when you try creating UserMetadata you MUST send the user ID value. It is the ID that tells JPA and the DB this is an existing user. If you don't know or can't send it, you'll have to add logic to your UserMetaServiceImpl or a layer underneath that takes the user and looks for it based on what ever natural identifier (username? email?) you can and then use that for the reference. Otherwise, JPA persists UserMetadata, sees a User without an identity and persists it too.

Comment: I have not changed any piece of code and try to send userId value when creating a UserMeta object, still don't work. Process and result: 1. Creates a User, sets user_id automatically to one. 2. Creates a UserMeta as: {
    "lastName":"foo", 
    "age":1, 
    "user":
    {
    "userId":1, 
    "username":"foo", 
    "password":"bar", 
    "email":"foo-bar"
    }
}. Result: A new entity in User with user_id with value two and a new UserMeta entity with userId with value two. Should I try another method instead of userMetaRepo.save(userMeta)?

Comment: You'll have to debug the save call and see what it does. I suspect it is not finding the UserMetadata instance (expected) and so just calls em.persist. Your provider then cascades persist on the User instance that is referenced, which requires the insert (or an exception if it exists). You'll want Spring to call merge instead, so that JPA detects on its own if the UserMetadata exists and then does the same for the User instance. Spring doesn't always do the right thing IMO. So another method (your own save implementation) that just calls entityManager.merge might work better here.

Comment: When saving the UserMeta obj with a user, embedded in JSON. The user is null. 
You don't happen to have a Repo or know a tutorial that shows this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: how can the user be null? Where is a new user instance coming from then?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this constructor in the User class,

```
 public User(String username, String email, String password, UserMeta userMeta) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userMeta = userMeta;
    }
```

now when you save your user the user Meta will be added to your UserMeta table,

If you want to add a user Meta to an existing user you will only need to set the userMeta and save it with a simple `userRepository.save(theUpdatedUser)`

you can also create userMeta seperately with your code above, and if you want to assign it to a user already in data base or not you can allows use the power of spring data and use simple `userRepository.save(userWithTheAssignedMeta)`

the same logic applies the other way for metaUser.

Comment: This won't help: The JSON creating a new UserMetadata object sends the User information but not the User ID, so there is no way for JPA to know the User data already exists.

Comment: It's mandatory to have an user information not the id specificaly. You can t add an information to something you don t know, so obviously the request should provide an information about the user and find the user with the user repositroy (for instance User userAlreadySaved = userRepository.findByName(username)) and then set it to the metauser (MyUserMeta.setUser(userAlreadySaved)) and save the metauser (metaUserRepository.save(MyUserMeta))

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your UserMetadata creation logic is using incomplete JSON:

```
{ "lastName":"foo", "age":1, "user":{ "username":"foo", "password":"bar", "email":"foo-bar" } }
```

Within this, the problem is the 'user' has all the data, duplicating what was already created the the database, but does not identify it. Since the mapping has cascade.ALL set on it, Spring/JPA will persist the UserMetadata and find this User instance that doesn't have identity, so persist it - giving it identity from the sequence.

There are a few ways you might correct this. First and easiest is to send the User ID in the json from the previously created instance:

```
{ "lastName":"foo", "age":1, "user":{ "userId":1, "username":"foo", "password":"bar", "email":"foo-bar" } }
```

This will allow Spring/JPA to recognize the user's identity and merge it and the data provided into the database. It means though that you must send complete data for the User - it will push incomplete data into the DB.

If that is a concern, you can change the cascade options. You may not want cascading persist/merge at all on this relationship, and I suspect when you delete userMetadata you don't really want to delete the User instance, so I think this might have been done incorrectly (maybe put it on the user->UserMetadata relationship instead?).  If you remove the cascade settings, spring/JPA will let you just pass in JSON with the USER id specified, as this gives it enough to set the fk:

```
{ "lastName":"foo", "age":1, "user":{ "userId":1} }
```

Comment: I tried both: 
` 
{ "lastName":"foo", "age":1, "user":{ "userId":1, "username":"foo", "password":"bar", "email":"foo-bar" } }
`

as well as changing cascade and working with { "lastName":"foo", "age":1, "user":{ "userId":1} }. 



**I must be allowed to create a User entity first as a parent and then UserMeta as a children entity, right?**

Comment: What happened when you tried specifying the user with its identity? Make sure you use the same format and ID as was returned from any create User operation. Yes, you are allowed to create a parent and then later a child that references the parent - it works in thousands of apps using JPA and is any number of tutorials. The trick is in managing identity so that JPA knows your parent instance (when creating the child) is the same parent instance you already created. Worst case, you have to look up the parent first, using the ID from what REST gives you, and point to it when calling save

Comment: **@Chris** So, when creating a new User. I receive the User attributes and values as a JSON. 
When I take the value of the User and send them in my post for userMeta as: {
    "lastname":"1",
    "user":{
    "username": "1",
    "password": "1",
    "email": "1",
    "id": 23
}
} . What happens is that I create get a new entity not only UserMeta but also User. Leaving me with a UserEntity with user_id with value of 24 and not 23. In my UserMeta I get no entity with value of 23. (So when creating a UserMeta, I also create a new User)

Comment: Sorry, the scenario I was asking about was when you send only the id for the user, and had changed the cascade options (presumably to remove cascade persist and cascade merge). JPA might not then try to insert a new instance, though it may, since the user instance is detached. Different providers handle it differently, especially within Spring. Best practice is to read it in yourself and use that managed instance in the reference if you don't want to have to merge in changes (opening up the application to accidental stale data overwrites).

Comment: Can you send me a tutorial or repo where this is working? Thank you

Comment: Should I flip relationship between parent and child, making UserMeta the parent table?